# In Triage reviews, does bad English grammar equal "Requires Editing"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I'm new to the review queues. Knowing that my own English isn't perfect at all either, does bad English or grammar require me to push the 'Requires Editing' button?

Comment: In short... yes.

Comment: Does poor grammar *require* you to choose the "Requires Editing"?  I say "No".  You have to assess whether the grammar significantly impacts readability and act accordingly.  Simple grammar (or even spelling) errors may have no impact at all the question, so do not need to be sent to editing.  The accepted answer in [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) states that you should send to "Requires Editing" to "Overhaul its substantial spelling/grammar/formatting errors" - the key word here is "substantial".